# Getting the JsonPath error: Expected to find an object with property ['id'] in path $ but found 'java.lang.String'

Tags: java, json

I want to get the path for a Json property and I am using the Json Path for parsing an Object in order to find the value of the property.

Unfortunately, I encounter the error: Expected to find an object with property ['id'] in path $ but found 'java.lang.String'. This is not a json object according to the JsonProvider: 'com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider'.

My code is below:

```
 String path = "$.id";
 return JsonPath.parse(document).read(path);
```

The json from which I want to extract the data (If I evaluate the JsonParse.parse(document)), is:

```
id:"12345678"
eventName:"MAINTAIN"
ind_Card:0
```

I am interested in getting the String value of the id. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Wild guess, but is this even valid json? There are no curly brackets around and as far as I know, the keys should also be in semicolons, so "id": "12345"

Comment: yes, it is - it is the result of the inspect stuff, this is why it looks like this

Comment: How are you reading `document` object? What libraries are you using?